# Conditionally rendered form fields not receiving focus on form submission when error occurs- React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want the form fields that are rendered conditionally in my form component to receive focus first (precedence) when the user attempts to submit the form when there's an error.

For instance, if a form field A is rendered conditionally but it's rendered above another form field B that's not rendered conditionally (always rendered), I want the form field A (rendered conditionally) to receive focus before form field B when the user attempts to submit the form when there's an error.

Currently, `RHF` seems to be skipping focus on form fields that are rendered conditionally despite the fields having errors.

Code:

**Form schema (zod):**

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  nameOfBusiness: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(260, { message: "The name is too long" }),
  modeOfPayment: z.string().nonempty({ message: "Please select an option" }),
  tillNumber: z
    .string()
    .nonempty({ message: "Please provide a value" })
    .min(5, { message: "Please enter a valid till number" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid till number" }),
 //...
});
```

**Form component:**

```
<div>
    <div>
      <h2>
        Mode of Payment
      </h2>
// 'Parent' form field
// Correctly gets focus precedence in case of error (not conditionally rendered)
      <select
        {...register("modeOfPayment", {
          onChange: (e) => {
            console.log(e, "event fired");
            setSelectedPaymentMode(e.target.value);
          },
        })}
        {/* ...*/}
      >
        <option value="" disabled={true}>
          Choose a mode of payment
        </option>
        <option>Mpesa Buy Goods</option>
        <option>Mpesa Paybill</option>
      </select>
      {errors?.modeOfPayment?.message && (
        <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">{errors.modeOfPayment.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>
// 'Child' form field
// Conditionally rendered (does not get focus precedence in case of error)
    {selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods" && (
      <div>
        <h2>
          Enter till number
          <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
        </h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          {...register("tillNumber")}
          {/* ... */}
        />
        {errors?.tillNumber?.message && (
          <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">{errors.tillNumber.message}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    )}
{/* other fields... */}
          <div>
            <h2>
              Name of business
            </h2>
// Not conditionally rendered (incorrectly gets focus precedence over form field that's conditionally rendered above)
            <input
              type="text"
              {...register("nameOfBusiness")}
              {/* .../*}
            />
            {errors?.nameOfBusiness?.message && (
              <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1 pl-4 lg:pl-8 min-[400px]:pl-6">
                {errors.nameOfBusiness.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/#Howtosharerefusage), React Hook Form needs a ref to collect the input value. However, you may want to use ref for other purposes (e.g. scroll into the view, or focus).

Change:

```
//tillNumber
        <input
          type="text"
          {...register("tillNumber")}
          {/* ... */}
        />
```

to:

```
//create refs for conditionally rendered fields
  const tillNumberRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const { ref: tillNoRef, ...restTillNumber } = register("tillNumber");

// form field
              <input
                {...restTillNumber}
                ref={(e) => {
                  tillNoRef(e);
                  tillNumberRef.current = e;
                }}
                type="text"
                {/* ... */}
              />
//repeat for other conditionally rendered form fields
```